# I want to save the updated value of global variable in notepad file and when i restart the server it should again start from the updated value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, global-variables

I have started the counter from 1. when i run the server the value of global variable increases as per while loop upto 9999. when i shut down the server and again restart it so it will again start from 1. i want to save the last count to the notepad file and whenever i restart the server it should take count from that notepad file

I have tried to save the but i am not able to do it.

```
global.n = 1
function getRequestID(){
var date = new Date();    
var month = date.getMonth()    
var year = date.getFullYear()
while(n<=9999){        
var ReqID = month + "-" + year + "-" + n;
n++;
return ReqID;
}   
}
```

I want to save the value of global variable in notepad if it is stopped at count 10 it will save 10 to notepad file when i again restart the server it should start from count 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, the number n will be saved to n_state.txt. If the file does not exist it will be created.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stateFileName = "n_state.txt";

global.n = loadN();

function loadN() { 
    if (!fs.existsSync(stateFileName)) return 1;
    return parseInt(fs.readFileSync(stateFileName, 'utf8'));
}

function saveN() {
    fs.writeFileSync(stateFileName, n);
}

function getRequestID() {
    var date = new Date();    
    var month = date.getMonth()    
    var year = date.getFullYear()
    while(n<=9999){        
        var ReqID = month + "-" + year + "-" + n;
        n++;
        saveN();
        return ReqID;
    }   
}

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let id = getRequestID();
    console.log("id: ", id);
}
```